# Access Remote SQL Server Database on WinCE programming

Tags: sql-server, lazarus

I'm programming using Lazarus (Freepascal IDE, Delphi Like), and i have a problem when i need to connect into a remote SQL Server database on the network.

My question:

1. Is there any way to connect to a remote SQLdb on Lazarus?
2. What is required connector type for SQL Server 2005?
3. Is there any ODBC driver available for Windows CE (Windows Mobile 5/6)? (If so, I could use TODBCConnection...)

I already searched and asked on the Lazarus community forum but didn't get any response

Answer (score 0):

Best to ask db component questions on the fpc-pascal or fpc-devel list.

1. ? Can't you simply configure that in the connection component by inserting a dns name/IP?
    The exact way is typically db-dependant. (connectionstrings)
2. ODBC (*)
3. Apparantly not default. Maybe 3rd party substitutes can be found.

(*) I'm planning to convert the ADO headers this summer, but it will probably take some time for the db devels to build components on top.